# Group items on slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, slider

I'm pretty new here and also with coding, I need help figuring out how to group items on a slider I have working on my website, so the thing is I want to classify them and group them, I wanna show 3 together then 2 others and then 4 each group with a title on top different for each one.

I can't do it cause it shows 4 slides every time I click on the arrows for the transitions, I can't find how to customize the number of slides to show on each transition.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it or at least what would you recommend in this situation?

[image: Logo on website]

I'm trying to modify this over "miSlider jQuery Plugin".
http://www.mislider.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Try using [Bootstrap carousels](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In a plugin there is a option called `slidesOnStage` which handle how many slide you want show at one time. You can use `slidesOnStage` like this.

```
 var slider = $('.YourDivClass').miSlider({
       //  Number of slides visible at one time. 
      //  Options: false or positive integer. 
     //  false = Fit as many as possible.
      slidesOnStage: 1, // If you use only 1 option remove `,` from last

    });
```

For more option [read documentation.](http://www.mislider.com/)